# When the user write the first name and the last name boxs I want it to get print it in cell using tkinter and python-docx, how can I do that?

Tags: python

I have a program for generating word document using docx-python and I want to design a GUI using tkinter. So, when I enter,for example, the name I want that be print it in the word document in a table, how can I code for such thing ?

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title("Registration")

label_1 = Label(root, text="FullName",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_1.place(x=80,y=130)
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_1.place(x=240,y=130)

root.mainloop()
document = Document()
t = document.add_table(rows=3, cols=2, style='TableGrid')
for row in t.rows:
    row.height = Inches(0.4)
cell = t.cell(0, 0)
cellp=cell.paragraphs[0]
#here where I want the name get print it
cellp.text='Name : '
cellp.add_run(FullName)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add button to the GUI because nothing is going to be executed after `root.mainloop()` without an event. So, let's add a button:

```
add_btn = Button(root)
add_btn["text"] = "Add name"
add_btn["command"] = add_to_document
add_btn.place(x=240,y=160)
```

In the example above `add_btn` will call `add_to_document` function whenever "Add name" is clicked.

This is where you need to have your document logic.

Here is a working example with a button and a function that prints contents of the text field when this button is pressed.

```
def add_to_document():
    print("Adding " + entry_1.get())

from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title("Registration")

label_1 = Label(root, text="FullName",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
label_1.place(x=80,y=130)
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_1.place(x=240,y=130)

# Adding a button
add_btn = Button(root)
add_btn["text"] = "Add name"
add_btn["command"] = add_to_document
add_btn.place(x=240,y=160)

root.mainloop()
```

There are other ways to do it and also a lot better ways to organize things. I suggest giving https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html a read.

They have a "hello world" example you can draw some inspiration from. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I want to convert the entry of the box name as string variable (like FullName) and to be added to the word document after I execute the code. here cellp.text='Name : ' cellp.add_run(FullName)

Comment: You can get text from the entry box using `entry_1.get()`. The rest of your logic you can put inside `add_to_document`.

Comment: I have used the get() method, but it didn't work.